# Javascript Syntaxhighlighting lost when AJAX call is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page on my website that I am making a call to using a jQuery ajax call. It loads in a div. But whenever I the page is loaded, it loses the snytax highlighting that it should be displaying. Ex:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- syntax highlighting script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- div that displays ajax page cal -->
<div id="awesomeo">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works on the initial page load if I have something in `awesomeo` but if a page is loaded via AJAX into the div, the syntax disappears.

EDIT:
The following is the code that is in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushBash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushCpp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushCss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushJava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushPhp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/shBrushPlain.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/shCore.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/shThemeDefault.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = '/scripts/clipboard.swf';
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

This is from: http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter 
That is all that is used for syntax highlighting... Suggestions?

Comment: if you could kindly explain what your syntax highlighter does and how it does it it would help. For example do you have a CSS file? do you use a $(document).read() or onload() to change the div content or it's styles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:
Adding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
</script>
```

on the page being called works.

Answer (score 1):

your syntaxhighlighter probably has a function bound to document.onload. You'll need to find that function and call it again.

Answer (score 0):

How is your syntax highlighting function called? If the syntax highlighting is fired on a body onload() event, it will obviously not work after an AJAX call because the body is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the ajax response, write this code there too to re-style the code.

```
// your ajax respone code here and after that:
SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = '/scripts/clipboard.swf';
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```